# Not able to capture SICF Services of Fiori LaunchPad OData Service's(/UI2/ namespace) in TR

Tags: odata, sap-fiori

In Development Server, I had ran Task "SAP_FIORI_LAUNCHPAD_INIT_SETUP" through stc01 transaction which created the below Odata Services with respective SICF services.

o ZINTEROP

o ZPAGE_BUILDER_PERS

o ZPAGE_BUILDER_CONF

o ZPAGE_BUILDER_CUST

o ZTRANSPORT

But since I wanted to get all the above ODATA Services and it's respective SICF services in TR to get it released for Quality.Therefore, I deleted all the above odata services and added manually through /IWFND/MAINT_SERVICE transaction.

But the SICF Services is not captured in the TR, hence after releasing to Quality,I can only see the ODATA Services and it's ICF node is showing Initial .PFB the TR screenshot.

[image: TR Screenshot]

[image: ICF Node]

Please Guide.

Regards,

Sayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In development system, did you create your services as part of a development package or as temporary local objects?
Please see the prerequisites in: [Transporting ICF Services](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nwpi711/helpdata/en/48/d402971904154ee10000000a421937/content.htm)

You should be able to add your services to a transport request, using transaction SICF:  “Right-click on your service -> Object Directory Entry”
as mentioned here in the following:
[Missing entry in SICF services after webservice transporting](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/979708),
[How to get a SICF Node for a imported BSP?](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3898651),
[How to transport web dynpro application](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/192158), and 
[Help, SICF Service is not transported](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/984136)

Comment: I have referred your link "Help,SICF Service is not transported" . I changed it from local Object to my ZPackage and saved it in TR and transported the same to Quality system. Still the SICF Service is showing Initial

Comment: When you say, the SICF service is showing “initial”, what does that mean ?
A screenshot would be helpful.
In https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70ehp2/helpdata/en/f2/22df3a750f6a02e10000000a11405a/content.htm it says:
“If anonymous logon data exists for a service, this data is deleted when the service is transported. This means that you may need to enter it again.“

If the service is transported, it might be inactive in the target system. Is this the issue ?

Comment: I had attached screenshot of ICF Node from Quality Server.The service does not exist if checked through SICF transaction.Hence it is showing as Initial.

Comment: 1)
You mentioned that you did refer to this link "Help,SICF Service is not transported" (https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/984136) :
(SICF -> Right-click on your service -> Object Directory Entry)
Here you saved a transport request and transported it to Quality system.
Was the SICF service not included in this transport request?
Which objects were included?

2)
Local temporary objects ($TMP) cannot be transported.
This is probably the reason why the service was not included in your very first transport request.

Answer (score 0):

1)
Your ICF node “ODATA” shown in your screenshot is active?

2)
When you saved your service in the transport request, it should be included as `R3TR SICF YourServiceName`.
When you transported this transport request to your Quality system, there should be a log of the import. You should see that your service was imported with `returncode=0.`

When I start transaction SICF, I get the following screen:
[image]

When I click “Execute (F8)”, I get the following screen:
[image]

Here I can search for services, e.g. by expanding “default_host”.

How does this look in your system ?

Comment: As per my screenshots,While manually adding the Odata services through /IWFND/MAINT_SERVICE transaction,at that point the ICF Services was not asked to get saved in TR.Hence the R3TR SICF ServiceName is not captured in TR.